# Чистый код в джанго

Tags: python, django, django-model

При создании моделей в одном из приложений джанго возник вопрос, стоит ли разбивать валидаторы по частям, например в `validate_cyrillic = RegexValidator(regex=r'^[А-Яа-яЁё]+$', message=CYRILLIC_ERROR_MESSAGE)` я вынес сообщение о возможной ошибке в константу наверх файла. То есть сейчас сверху файла models.py лежат все сообщения о возможных ошибках; все валидаторы находятся рядом с полем, к которому применяются (все валидаторы применяются только единожды, нет таких которые могли бы примениться сразу к двум полям); регулярные выражения никуда не вынесены и лежат в самом валидаторе. В таком случае я вижу несколько проблем: если захочется изменить регулярку в каком-то валидаторе, придется листать файл models.py или если я захочу изменить название валидатора, также придется искать его в фале. Подскажите как решить эти проблемы, может вынести и регулярки, и сообщения об ошибках в отдельный файл validators.py (или просто наверх models.py), или вынести сами валидаторы?